# Query is not executing (Want to get sysdate on the right side of expression)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a date column whose type is `DATE` and values are of the form `23-AUG-12, 09-FEB-12.` Now i am trying to run a query but i am getting error that

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Here is the query. Actually i want to get the current date on the right side of `first_appr_dt = current date`

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No." from losa_app LOSA_APP where 
LOSA_APP.app_status='A' and first_appr_dt = 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY') from dual);
```

What i am doing wrong ? Please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column `first_appr_dt` is really a `DATE` column, then there's no need to to compare the dates as string. In fact, it's probably the source of the problem.

Furthermore, there's no need select from DUAL for this simple expression.

You rather want:

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No." from losa_app LOSA_APP
where LOSA_APP.app_status = 'A' and first_appr_dt = trunc(sysdate);
```

Note, that the query uses `TRUNC` to remove the time from the date as your table probably contains dates with the time set to 00:00:00. If not, then you should try the following condition:

```
trunc(first_appr_dt) = trunc(sysdate)
```

If you really want to compare the dates as strings, then you would need to use `TO_CHAR` for both sides of the comparison:

```
to_char(first_appr_dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No." from losa_app LOSA_APP where 
LOSA_APP.app_status='A' and first_appr_dt = 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY') from dual);
```

Comment: No, when i try to run query then now i get the following error `ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"`

Comment: Also if i use `(SELECT TO_CHAR('23-AUG-12', 'DD-MMM-YY') from dual)` then i get the error `ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"`

Comment: No even if i try this query `(SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MOM-YY')"Now" FROM DUAL); or MOM` seperately i get the `ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"`. This works seperately `(SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YY')"Now" FROM DUAL);`. I think there is something wrong with the month (MMM) ......